# How can I access the content of main website from subdomain using relative path?

Tags: apache, subdomain, cpanel

For example, I have a hlo.wrld.com subdomain of wrld.com, which is located in /public_html/hlo in cpanel. In hlo directory I have a index.html file which contains:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
<p>Anything, just checking that font is loaded</p>
<img src="../img1">
```

But this relative paths doesn't work. So how can I access the content of wrld directory using relative paths?

Comment: where is the content of wrld.com?

Comment: at the /public_html/

Comment: if relative path doesnt work, why dont you just do <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://wrld.com/style.css">